# Applying outer layer that wrapping two select statement

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two query which has successfully inner join

```
select t1.countResult, t2.sumResult from (
    select 
        count(column) as countResult
    from tableA join tableB 
    on tableA.id = tableB.id
    group by name
)t1 inner join (    
    select 
        sum(column) as sumResult
    from tableA
    join tableB
    on tableA.id = tableB.id
    group by name
)t2 
on t1.name= t2.name
```

The above query will return me the name and the corresponding number of count and the sum. I need to do a comparison between the count and sum. If the count doesnt match the sum, it will return 0, else 1. And so my idea was implementing another outer layer to wrap them up and use `CASE WHEN`. However, I've failed to apply an outer layer just to wrap them up? This is what I've tried:

```
select * from(
    select t1.countResult, t2.sumResult from (
        select 
            count(column) as countResult
        from tableA join tableB 
        on tableA.id = tableB.id
        group by name
    )t1 inner join (    
        select 
        sum(column) as sumResult
        from tableA
        join tableB
        on tableA.id = tableB.id
        group by name
    )t2 
    on t1.name= t2.name
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright the problem can be solved by simply assigning a name to the outer layer.

```
select * from(
select t1.countResult, t2.sumResult from (
    select 
        count(column) as countResult
    from tableA join tableB 
    on tableA.id = tableB.id
    group by name
)t1 inner join (    
    select 
    sum(column) as sumResult
    from tableA
    join tableB
    on tableA.id = tableB.id
    group by name
)t2 
on t1.name= t2.name
) as whatever  //SQL Server need a name to wrap
```

Hope it will help any newbie like me

Comment: This will only show the records where countresult = sumresult, while when using a case, you probably want something to show both kinds of records, but what you actually show depends on the result of your case statement.

Comment: Nope, it will list out the countResult and the sumResult for each of the name. I've tested and it works fine.

Comment: Right.  Somehow I mixed up the t1.name=t2.name with countresult=sumresult. Sorry 'bout that!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so far you have selected everything your first select has generated (kinda useless, but a start for what you want ;) )

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN countresult=sumresult THEN 'Equal'
ELSE 'Not'
END
FROM ( --your join select --
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any sample data to test this so can just go on your code.
Your queries for t1 & t2 look identical - why don't you just do a sum & count in 1 step?

```
SELECT COUNT(column) AS countResult
,SUM(column) AS sumResult
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB 
    ON tableA.id = tableB.id
GROUP BY name
```

Also, as you mention you are a newb - read up on Common Table Expressions in SQL Server.
Before SQL 2005 you had to write these convoluted queries within queries within...
Get into the habit of using CTEs now.